# floated element not float at current line

Tags: css

In [css2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#comp-float), there is an example for comparing float with others, when the inner span not float:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Comparison of positioning schemes</TITLE>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { display: block; font-size:12px; line-height: 200%; width: 400px; height: 400px }
        p    { display: block }
        span { display: inline }
        #outer { color: red }
        #inner { color: blue }
        #inner { width: 130px; color: blue }
    </style>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <P>Beginning of body contents.
      <SPAN id="outer"> Start of outer contents.
      <SPAN id="inner"> Inner contents.</SPAN>
      End of outer contents.</SPAN>
      End of body contents.
    </P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and when the inner span float:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Comparison of positioning schemes</TITLE>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { display: block; font-size:12px; line-height: 200%; width: 400px; height: 400px }
        p    { display: block }
        span { display: inline }
        #outer { color: red }
        #inner { color: blue }
        #inner { float: right; width: 130px; color: blue }
    </style>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <P>Beginning of body contents.
      <SPAN id="outer"> Start of outer contents.
      <SPAN id="inner"> Inner contents.</SPAN>
      End of outer contents.</SPAN>
      End of body contents.
    </P>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am confused why when it's floated, the inner span seems to drop to the second line, is this rule in sepc:

> The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any line-box containing a box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

results the position? But in the [picture in spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#img-flow-float), it seems not to drop, just floating to right at the current line. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Where are you seeing the inner span dropping to the second line? I don't see it happening in any browser.

Comment: My browser is chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). I recheck this in safari and it doesn't happen. Maybe it's browser-related. Should I close the question? And many thanks for you to answer my questions!

Comment: Well it certainly is an edge case, floats interacting with line breaks is an area that's not very well defined by the spec. No problem.